# Raspberry PI cannot run gitlab image on docker

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, gitlab

I am trying to run docker image with gitlab on my Raspberry PI.

Versions:

```
Raspbian 10 (buster)
Docker 20.10.8, API 1.41
Gitlab CE 13.10.0-ce.0 from [this][1] image, ulm0/gitlab 12.7.2
```

I am using simply docker command to run gitlab:

```
sudo docker run --name gitlab \ 
-p 10080:80 -p 10022:22 -p 10443:443 \
-v /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
-v /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
-v /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab -v \
/srv/gitlab/logs/reconfigure:/var/log/gitlab/reconfigure \
ulm0/gitlab
```

After running a command, in `sudo docker logs gitlab` I've got something like this:

```
Configure GitLab for your system by editing /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file
And restart this container to reload settings.
To do it use docker exec:

  docker exec -it gitlab vim /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
  docker restart gitlab

For a comprehensive list of configuration options please see the Omnibus GitLab readme
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md

If this container fails to start due to permission problems try to fix it by executing:

  docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions
  docker restart gitlab
```

but after running `docker exec -it gitlab update-permissions` I've got this:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 110f1def3f669d8d180bf552aa63e50c0e4c857f8bd1ab2745a677454fef04b0 
is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

when I ran command with permissions right after container stared, I got `unable to upgrade to tcp, received 409` and now I stuck, because I can not even log into my machine, it's restarting all the time. I tried to change port to more custom, but it's also dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `latest` version, but I have changed it to `ulm0/gitlab:12.10.0` and it works. Sounds like a bug in a new version.